# Bouncing car, notice every gap when driving

Tags: nissan, suspension, shock-absorber, springs, micra

I own a Micra K11 from 1999 for some months now.

The car has been lowered with lowering springs. The thing is, that the car is really bouncy, but when driving over a threshold or something, it instead feels like the shockabsorbers or springs are really tight.

Is the bouncing / noticing of almost every unevenness in the road due to the shock absorbers or springs? Are they worn out or is it just because the car has been lowered or because it is old (so maybe the suspension is just like that)?

I have driven in a Toyota Starlet, and this car was really fluent on the road, even though it was even older than my car.

I'd like to point out that my handling of the car is not bad. Going over bumps and thresholds are less comfortable than I've experienced in other cars and I wondered if this may be due to the springs or shock dampers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Car with modified suspension will have different ride characteristics than a standard car with stock suspension. So, your comparison may not be very useful.

I once had a car that was lowered with a performance suspension. It had a stiff ride, as designed for improved cornering. It was rough on less than smooth roads.

In your case, the chances are good that the lowering kit was also to improve performance. Thus the stiffer shocks and rougher ride. What we cannot tell you is the condition of the shocks/springs from what information you have given. They may be working correctly or could be worn out. Check to see what brand they are and contact the manufacturer for how to check for wear.

If you do not like the ride quality, switch it back to the stock springs and shocks. Then it may ride more like the Toyota you compared it to.

Comment: Okay thank you for your response! But  for some reason the car felt 'stiff'  when driving over small unevennesses, but bouncy when braking / moving around in the car. But this is pointed out in the question @NitrusInc pointed out. I will check out the springs and maybe have the stock ones put back!

Comment: @bramulous the stiff ride can be addressed to the stiffer lowering springs, but the "bouncy" part may be because the shock absorbers are shot.